# put time as string to the query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

The query works fine but since I must test my project several time and I dont want always to adjust the arrivaltime table to the current time I would integrate a string `time` to the query but I am getting the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':56,'%H:%i') and name LIKE 'hbf'' at line 1

The time must include only the hours as well minutes digits.

```
            String time = "12:56:00";
            PreparedStatement preparedTime = con
                                .prepareStatement("SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops"
                                        + " ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id "
                                        + "WHERE weekday = '"
                                        + day
                                        + "'"
                                        //+ " and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') and name LIKE '"
                                        + " and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format("+ time+ ",'%H:%i') and name LIKE '"

                                        + stop_name + "'");

            ResultSet rsArrivaletime = preparedTime.executeQuery();
```

Comment: `PreparedStatement` and string concatenation???

Comment: @RC. Yes please can you tell me what can I use else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `PreparedStatement`, **NEVER CONCATENATE STRINGS TO GET THE QUERY, EVER**. Pass the proper time as `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Timestamp` as parameters.

```
String sql =
    "SELECT route FROM arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops"
    + " ON arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id"
    + " WHERE weekday = ?"
    + " and arrivaltime = ?"
    + " and name LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement preparedTime = con
    .prepareStatement(sql);
preparedTime.setString(1, day);
//preparing the proper time using java.util.Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//create an instance of java.sql.Time
//Calendar#getTime returns an instance of java.util.Date
//Date#getTime returns the time in millis (long)
Time time = new Time(cal.getTime().getTime());
//setting the time
preparedTime.setTime(2, time);
preparedTime.setString(3, stopname);
ResultSet rs = preparedTime.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting at this line `preparedTime.setTime(time);` this error `The method setTime(int, Time) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (Time)`

Comment: @TheTime how are you declared `time` variable? Probably you have another variable called `time` and you just copied/pasted the code without even analyzing it...

Comment: `Time time = new Time(cal.getTime().getTime());`  I have typed it and did not copied/pasted it.  `import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Calendar;`

Comment: Then I don't know what exact problem you have. This compiles fine in my environment.

Comment: The problem was the first parameter `2`  `preparedTime.setTime(time);` ;)

Comment: Great you discovered it. Please comment about any other issue.

Comment: I have problem I debugged it and I am getting this query `SELECT route FROM arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops ON arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id WHERE weekday = 'mon-fri' and arrivaltime = '00:56:00' and name LIKE 'hbf'` instead of `12:56:00` I am getting `00:56:00`?

Comment: Fixed the answer. Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `Calendar.HOUR`.

Comment: I have the following ` Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56); cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);`